# Conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en smalldatetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony4

Concretamente este es el error que me sale cuando ejecuto una consulta en mi base de datos

`SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en smalldatetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.`

Como puedo formatear los datos para que la consulta funcione correctamente? Desde el cliente de SQL server puedo ejecutarla y funciona, pero desde syfmony cuando la lanzo me da el error de arriba

Comment: Sería bueno que en futuras preguntas consideres agregar el código que genera errores.

Comment: No puedo publicar ese código ya que contiene datos privados

Comment: FYI [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), para tu pregunta solo se hubiera necesitado el valor y la forma como lo estabas convirtiendo, la parte que te genera error.  Ahora para el nombre de columnas y tabla, sencillamente se renombra.

Answer (score -1):

La solución es `convert(datetime, 'valor', 120)`

El 120 es el estilo (yyyy-dd-mm H:i:s)

Comment: Sería bueno que mejoraras tu respuesta, hay sitios como sqlfiddle si tu respuesta aplica a base de datos, pero por lo que pusiste, realmente no entiendo si es un cambio de sql o de php. Saludos.